# Is there a general way to prove that PX, PY, PZ are in GP without specifically letting A to be on y-axis?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, circles, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

> Let BC be the chord of contact of the tangents from a point A to the circle $x^2+y^2=1.$ P is any point on the arc BC. Let PX, PY, PZ be the lengths of perpendiculars from P on the AB, BC and CA respectively then prove that PX, PY, PZ are in Geometric Progression.

Let A be $(0,\alpha)\implies$ equation of BC is $\alpha y=1$

$\implies$ B and C are $(\frac{-\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}{\alpha},\frac1\alpha), (\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}{\alpha},\frac1\alpha)$

$\implies$ equation of AB and AC are $\frac{-\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}{\alpha}x+\frac y\alpha=1$ and $\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}{\alpha}x+\frac y\alpha=1$

and PZ$=|\cos\theta  \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}{\alpha}+\frac{\sin\theta}\alpha   -1|$, where P $=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$

$\implies$ PY$^2=$PX$\cdot$PZ

Comment: Begin by showing $\triangle PXB \sim \triangle PZC$ and $\triangle PXC \sim \triangle PYB$

Comment: @HariShankar isn't that giving us $PX^2=PY\cdot PZ?$

Comment: Right. I have taken $X$ as foot of perp on $BC$. You can modify accordingly

Comment: @HariShankar thanks. If you want, you may post this as an answer, maybe as one-liner hint. I'll accept it and close the post.

Comment: See my #5 in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2991669. Identical apart from labels. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5LTM.png .

Comment: @youthdoo thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by showing △PYB∼△PZC and △PYC∼△PXB (uses Alternate Segment Theorem)